# Some SiteCatalyst eVar values not passing in Custom Link

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm facing a crazy matter with a SiteCatalyst Custom Link (internal) request.
I'm firing an s.tl() through the code below:

```
var s_custom = s_gi("report-suite");
s_custom.linkTrackVars = "eVar76,events,list3";
s_custom.linkTrackEvents = "event87";
s_custom.events = "event87";
s_custom.eVar76 = "value";
s_custom.list3 = "option1,option2";
s_custom.tl(this, 'o', 'link name');
```

The issue concerns the **eVar76**, whose value is not included in the request, even if the "s_custom" TrackerObject contains it. In fact, if I inspect that object I find it.
This strange seems to affect just "high" number  eVars, like eVar76, 77, 80, 99 and so on, not lower ones.
Replacing eVar76 with eVar55, 56 or 60, for ex, is resulting in a normale behaviour where values are normally included in requests.
**This is not depending on eVars existance, or activation, in the report suite** and this is expected because no preliminar calls are made to Adobe server in order to check the set, or enabled, eVars in that report suite.
This is a very silly behaviour forcing me to replace the desired eVar with another one.
I just add that this Custom Link is prepared by a Page-load (DOM ready) rule in the Adobe DTM, but I suppose that no particular setting should be done in order to fix it.
This is the first time that an SC variable is not included in request as expected.
Thanks so much for supporting me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core Adobe Analytics library code builds the request string with a loop that looks for events/eVars up to the max available. Adobe Analytics only recently expanded events from 100 to 1000 and eVars from 75 to 100/250, so in order to accommodate this increase, an update to the core AppMeasurement library code was made.

**Note:** Although Adobe has been making updates to the Legacy H library alongside AppMeasurement, they did *not* update the Legacy H library to accommodate this increase. So, in order to track `eVar76`+ and `event101`+ within javascript as the variable (e.g. `s.eVar76='foobar'`), you must upgrade to the latest AppMeasurement library.

Alternatively, if you are using Legacy H.23+ library you can instead populate it as a [`contextData` variable](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/context_data_variables.html) and then map it to the event/eVar/prop in a processing rule (e.g. `s.contextData['eVar76']='foobar'` and then in processing rule you'd have e.g. `if [(contextdata) eVar76] [is set] then overwrite [eVar76] with [(contextdata) eVar76]`)

**Reference:** https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/evars_events.html

Comment: Thank you @Crayon, helpful as usual. We've been used to the H.x library until now and I didn't know about this warning. I think we'll harness the contextData solution.

Comment: thanks to your answer i've been able to leverage eVar76 and above! I'm using this method to populate eVar92 which I assumed was working. I can see the variable get populated in the network log / image request. problem is that it doesn't seem to get passed into siteCat. i've been testing in staging over the last week and there is still nothing - i should be seeing something right?

Comment: @FinbarMaginn you should post your own question with details about how you've configured eVar92 vs. use in javascript. It may not be getting a value for a number of reasons, e.g. if it's disabled or if you've set it to product syntax but pop it as its own var.  Also may need to talk to your account rep or client care and ensure your account is actually provisioned to use it. eVar76-100 appears in your config even if you aren't provisioned for it!